# Assembly equivalent of _mm_set_epi8 with zeros for all but the last parameter

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, simd

I am writing a program for passing the subject at the university,which should compare efficiency of C++ & SIMD function and assembly function. For now, I managed to do the first one quite well, but during the second one, I found a problem:

In my C++ function I have a line of code like this:

```
XXX_R0 = _mm_set_epi8(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, RedForAll);
```

in which RedForAll is given in parameters of my function:

```
void CppSIMDFunction(unsigned char *src, short RedForAll, short GreenForAll, short BlueForAll)
```

I thought about allocating a memory like this:

```
.DATA
Red db 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, X
```

and then somehow save this RedForAll at position marked with X, but how to do that?

I am afraid `movdqa` won't be useful in this case, as I need to load value from register to memory in a particular place, so how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you programming for x86?  Note that x86 doesn't have an `ldr` instruction, so I'm not quite sure what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is x64. Meanwhile, I found something about vpbroadcastb, but I am not sure how to use it correctly. Unforunately I am forced to do this project, without any practical exercises before, so I am totally a newbie in case of assembly.

Comment: `vpbroadcastb` broadcasts, it doesn't load a single byte and fill the rest with zeroes, so it's not equivalent to your original code. Anyway, the assembly solution depends on where `RedForAll` comes from. Is it in a register? Memory? (if it's a function parameter, where it is depends on the calling convention, which this question has not specified)

Comment: It is char given as a function parameter

Comment: Note that `_mm_set_xxx()` intrinsics take their args in highest-first order.  But `db` goes in lowest-address-first order.  Also, if you want the high elements zeroed, use a `movd` or `movq` load, not `movdqa`.

Comment: Did you just take a look at what your compiler generates for that intrinsic? E.g.: https://godbolt.org/z/hqergU (depending on context or target architecture, other constructs may be better)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `movd` (when using SSE) or `vmovd` after zero-extending appropriately:

```
; assuming RedForAll is in cl
movzx eax, cl     ; zero extend al into eax
movd xmm0, eax    ; copy eax into xmm0 and clear the upper 96 bits
```